# nhibernate multicriteria CTE subquery

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, criteria-api

I currently have a MultiCriteria query, which filters the results based on the ids being within a sub query

`Subqueries.PropertyIn("Id", detachedCriteria)`

The sub query is the same for all queries used in the multicriteria query.

It seems a bit ugly looking at the sql that the sub query is repeated, in my current case 15 times.

The reason for the separate queries is each one has different joins, and don't want one massive Cartesian join.

If I was writing the sql by hand I would pull out the repeated sub query into a common table expression

```
WITH XYZ AS
{
    ....
}
```

and then the sub query would be where id in XYZ in the 15 queries.

This is a bit sql server specific, an alternative would be a temporary table, or other database specific feature.

Any ideas of how to improve the query, or am I stuck with the sub queries being duplicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you're returning multiple result sets, using `WITH` won't help you anyways because it can only apply to a single `SELECT` statement.

In any event, to make the data layer code database-agnostic, I would probably shove the actual query logic into a stored procedure. This means you can go to town using engine-specific features because it's all hidden behind the public interface. Yes, you'll have to reimplement the query for each database engine you support (which is normally very few), but you get full control over what gets run on each engine, and your data access code will be a heck of a lot cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for the info, having read your advice found this article confirming what you say. http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Understanding_SQL_Complex_Queries.aspx "One thing of note is that a CTE can only be used once in your query. So you can't declare your CTE at the top, then do multiple queries against it. However, you can make multiple CTE's and then use them together in one query. Also, everything has it's place, so if you find that you are building the same CTE multiple times for different reports / queries, then you might want to turn that into a VIEW instead."

Comment: In my case I can't create a stored procedure, as is a dynamic query. And creating a view for each dynamic query is going to be slower, eat up transaction log (could put in another linked database with simple recovery mode). Good to know anyway CTE wouldn't help me in my scenario.

Comment: @Ian: You *can* use a stored procedure. Just pass it all the input parameters used in your NHibernate query. If it's a lot of parameters, or lists of things (ids, for example), you could consider passing the parameters as XML.

Comment: I'm using a dynamic sql generated by NHibernate, this is a very complex query and lots of optional filters. Each query can be different. So in my case I can't use a stored procedure. I know NHibernate supports stored procedures, and that inside stored procedures you can use dynamic sql.